# Sign difference in eigenvectors taken form Matlab and Python

Tags: python, matlab, python-2.7, linear-algebra, eigenvector

Could you please explain why there is a sign difference in some of the eigenvectors (2-4)? Does this difference affect further calculation in further calculations, e.g dimensionality reduction?

**Matlab:**

```
N = 5000;
dataA = rand(N,5);
covA = cov(dataA);
%covA = dataA*dataA'/(length(dataA)-1);
covA = covA + eps.*eye(size(covA));
[~,pA] = chol(covA);
assert(pA==0,'A is not possitive definite')

dataB = rand(N,5);
covB = cov(dataB);
%covB = dataB*dataB'/(length(dataB)-1);
covB = covB + eps.*eye(size(covB));
[~,pB] = chol(covB);
assert(pB==0,'B is not possitive definite')

[V,D] = eig(covA, covB);

V =

   -0.4241   -1.0891    1.8175    2.4067   -1.3032
    1.4445   -1.8960   -1.4118   -0.6514   -2.0075
    0.1214   -2.5039    0.3332   -0.1705    2.3609
   -2.1235   -0.7007    1.1632   -2.1532   -1.0554
   -2.2599   -0.4405   -2.2236    1.2545    0.0760
```

**Python:**

```
from scipy.linalg import eigh
import scipy.io
import numpy as np

cov_mat = scipy.io.loadmat('cov.mat')
covA = cov_mat['covA']
covB = cov_mat['covB']
eigvals, eigvecs = eigh(covA, covB, eigvals_only=False)

np.savetxt('eigvals.txt', eigvals, fmt='%.4f')
np.savetxt('eigvecs.txt', eigvecs, fmt='%.4f')

eigvecs =

   0.4241 1.0891 -1.8175 -2.4067 -1.3032
  -1.4445 1.8960  1.4118  0.6514 -2.0075
  -0.1214 2.5039 -0.3332  0.1705  2.3609
   2.1235 0.7007 -1.1632  2.1532 -1.0554
   2.2599 0.4405  2.2236 -1.2545  0.0760
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are the same eigenvectors, as flipping the signs on eigenvectors does not change their formulation - they will have the same eigenvalue. It will not affect further calculations as a result.

*Why* are they calculated differently? 
Most likely because the subroutines that are run vary based on the matrix that is being operated on, and don't care what 'sign' they return because eigenvalues don't have one.

---

*A trivial mathematical proof*:

If `x` is an eigenvector of matrix `A` with eigenvalue `q`, then by definition we have that `Ax = qx`.

It follows that `A(-x) = -(Ax) = -(qx) = q(-x)` such that `-x` is an eigenvector with the same eigenvalue.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes the have the same eigenvalues but what about the last eigen vector (`-V` is not the same as `eigvecs`) ?

Comment: @Darkmoor Eigenvectors _don't_ have a sign, so the fact they are the same for that eigenvector is also fine. If you know any linear algebra you know the concept of eigenvectors relates to shape, which does not change with scaling factors and sign changes so long as individual elements aren't changing on their own.

Comment: So eigenvectors show orientation of the shape whose scale (how much sphere or ellipsoid) depends on eigenvalue. Thus the direction of eigenvectors which is affected by the sign is not a problem because the orientation is our concern. Am I right? Thanks again.

Comment: @Darkmoor if you imagine an eigenvector as an infinite line in space, its direction is not changed when multiplied by the matrix, it doesn't matter which way the line is expressed, going from left to right or right to left (figuratively), it's still the same line. Thus, it doesn't matter which way the sign points, it is just an artifact of the numerical computation.

Comment: But...If I project data onto the axes defined by those eigenvectors, wouldn't the data then be inverted between that projection and one that use the same eigenvectors with opposite signs?